# Possibilities to employ/control/"embed" the gecko rendering engine?

Tags: browser, embed, mozilla, gecko

What is the current way to go if you want to employ/instrument/"embed" the gecko rendering engine in a separate application? Is it to write a XUL based application and use libxul? Are there any up to date resources available, such as tutorials?

I need to display and maybe print web pages, load custom CSS, execute java script, all done locally. There are so many outdated resources, it's hard to figure out what's the proper way to achieve this. Even the official Mozilla site ([Embedding Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Embedding_Mozilla)) points to deprecated resources. There is a link to a new API ([NewAPI](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Embedding/NewApi)), that should simplify embedding, but it seems unmaintained and incomplete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The supported way to do this would be developing a XULRunner application. XULRunner is the stand-alone version of the Gecko engine, it can run any XUL-based applications. In particular, an application can use a `<browser type="content" />` tag to load and display web pages the same way Firefox does it. [Getting started with XULRunner](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Getting_started_with_XULRunner) is a nice introduction and there is [more documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XULRunner).

Comment: I see. I wasn't sure whether "Getting started with XULRunner" still applies, since the document is from over six years ago and talks of Firefox 3.

Comment: @curiosity: I looked through it and all the info seems current. What's more important, looking at the article history - Mark Finkle kept updating it.